# When to use django shortcut functions

Tags: django

When would you want to create a response object and return it from a view such as

```
return HttpResponse( ... )
```

instead of using a shortcut function like render() or redirect()?

Comment: If you can't think of a reason, *just don't*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpResponse` can only be passed in a HTML string and HTTP headers.
`HttpResponseRedirect` expects redirect URL string.

`render()` can be more fine tuned for auto-generated responses (via templates and contexts). It builds the proper `HttpResponse` object for you.

Likewise `redirect()` can automatically resolve URLs of your views (and even models!) and return a `HttpResponseRedirect` object.

For more specific information you should refer to the official django documentation.

Answer (score -1):

When you make your backend at Django and let the front end be elsewhere (may be Android/iOS app) then, You can sometimes return strings like "Success" using HttpResponse().

Comment: Why was it downvoted? I think the answer makes complete sense!